# Offline response caching with Retrofit 2 and OkHttp 3

Tags: android, caching, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm trying to cache response via OkHttp and Retrofit. I understand there are several questions similar to mine but none of those are able to address my issue.

Following is my Interceptor responsible for modifying the headers.

```
private static class CachingControlInterceptor implements Interceptor {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();

            Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(request);
            return originalResponse.newBuilder()
                    .header("Cache-Control", (UtilityMethods.isNetworkAvailable()) ?
                            "public, max-age=60" :  "public, max-stale=604800")
                    .build();
        }
    }
```

Now, this works perfectly in the first case -

1. Internet connection is available.
2. A valid response is received and cached.
3. Disconnect the device from the internet.
4. Send the same request as previous one within a minute -> Response is same as last
5. Next, send the same request after a minute is complete -> No response (`UnknownHostException`)

This makes the first part (`"public, max-age=60"`) complete.

But, somehow, `"public, max-age=60"` part does not work at all.

This part should enable okhttp to fetch the a week old stale data when the device is offline but instead, I get `UnknownHostException`.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for :

```
.header("Cache-Control", (UtilityMethods.isNetworkAvailable()) ?
            "public, max-age=60" :  "public, only-if-cached, max-stale=604800")
```

This adds the `only-if-cached` directive for when the network is unavailable.  This only accepts the response if it is in the cache.